# HTML - How can I hide a loading div when a new tab loads?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a button, when you click it shows a loading div and opens a new tab which loads an html. I want to hide this div when the html in the new tab loads. I've tried so many things to hide this but no one works, can I have some help? I'm new on html, javascript, ajax, jquery development.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    00% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
#white-background{
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            background-color: #fefefe;
            opacity: 0.7;
            z-index: 9999;
 }
 #dlgbox{
            /*initially dialog box is hidden*/
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            width: 480px;
            z-index: 9999;
            border-radius: 10px;

        }
 </style>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">         
</script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){


 $("#show").click(function(){
     $("div").show();
     var win = window.open("new2.html");    
 });

 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>


 <button id="show">Show</button>

 <center>
 <div id="loadingImage" style="display:none;">
 <div id="white-background"></div>
    <center>
    <div id="dlgbox">   
    <div class="loader"></div>  
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
    </center>
    </div>
 </div>
 </center>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Do not see any attempts to hide it.

Comment: You can't communicate across different tabs in js. You could do something server side where the second tab sends an event to your server that the first tab listens or polls for. Or you could just use a simple timeout. Either way, as soon as you open that new tab, your existing tab will go to the background and depending on the browser, it won't be visible, so your loading div might be irrelevant.

Comment: Based on your requirement, you should really add html tabs to your page and control the content that way. You would then have complete control.

Comment: If you are on same domain then use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

You can not  remove the loading if cause your browser IS in loading state. So you might ask google or mozilla to remove it ;) It just is shown cause your new window CAN NOT LOAD THE PAGE.To open a window is like open a new browser. Without "http://whatever" it will show a error 404 or in some case this "logo". So if you use a full qualified URL nothing is shown.  Your code has some more issues.
1.) jquery is depriated and overkill
2.) do not use such libs untilyou has understand javascript at its base !
3.) you should use chrome as developement browser - with F12 it opens a nice IDE which can clean up also your messy HTML code ;) Ther was some divs not correctly nested. Will mix up javascript and css.

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <style>
                    .loader {
                        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
                        /* Light grey */
                        border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
                        /* Blue */
                        border-radius: 50%;
                        width: 120px;
                        height: 120px;
                        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
                    }

                    @keyframes spin {
                        0% {
                            transform: rotate(0deg);
                        }

                        00% {
                            transform: rotate(360deg);
                        }
                    }

                    #white-background {
                        display: none;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        position: fixed;
                        top: 0px;
                        left: 0px;
                        background-color: #fefefe;
                        opacity: 0.7;
                        z-index: 9999;
                    }

                    #dlgbox {
                        /*initially dialog box is hidden*/
                        display: none;
                        position: fixed;
                        width: 480px;
                        z-index: 9999;
                        border-radius: 10px;
                    }
                </style>
                <head></head>
                <body>
                    <button id="show" onclick="javascript:winopen('new2.html');">Show</button>
                    <div id="progress" style="display:none;">
                        <div id="white-background">
                            <center>
                                <div id="dlgbox">
                                    <div class="loader"></div>
                                    <h1>Loading...</h1>
                                </div>
                            </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <script>
//if you load or put scripts at the end the DOM (direct before </body>) the 
//page html is already loaded so no need 
// for onload tricks The page is already ready here.
                        var win;
                        var progress;
                        var baseurl = ""
                        baseurl = window.location.href;//current page location
                        //current url
                        url = baseurl.split("/");
                        //remove current filname by split to array
                        url.pop();
                        //remove last array element
                        baseurl = url.join("/");
                        // join rest of array

                        console.log(baseurl);
                        function winopen(page) {
                            progress = document.getElementById("progress");// get the div by its id

                            //i have put the file in the same directory. i gues you has to change "/" to "/YOUR_SUBDIRECTORY e.g. /test//"
                            var href = baseurl + "/" + page; //create new url for the window open thing


                            progress.style.display = "block";// show the progress info
                            win = (window.open(href)); // open the window
                            progress.style.display = "none;"; // it's loaded hide the progress info
                        }

//bonus trick:

function content_manager(showme_id,hideme_id) {
   document.getElementById(hideme_id).style.display="none";
   document.getElementById(showme_id).style.display="block";
}
                    </script>
                </body>
            </html>
```

You own me a beer ;) BTW: you might not see you loading stage. Its too fast to see. Comment out the hide part or use the chrome debugger to se whats going on :)
To center things : [center a  info box](https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/) you might also read about the z-index css property. You can hide the whole page by a div with is width 100%  height 100% , has a frixed position and has a z-index: 2; so you put your loading info over the page and hide the page completely. You might use as background-color: rgba(1,1,1,.5) to make it half transparent ;)

Comment: BTW: with the display block trick you can put everything to be shown on the page already. (The whole thing) just hide them all and unhide them as needed.just hide and show them by id. Its very fast.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on same domain then try with `localStorage`:

Add this script:

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem("ispageloaded",false);
function load(){
var func=setTimeout(function(){
if(localStorage.getItem("ispageloaded")){
clearTimeout(func);
//Then hide loading div here...
}else{
load();
}
},2000);
}
load();
window.open("nav2.html","_blank");
</script>
```

Add this script to **nav2.html**:

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem("ispageloaded",true);
</script>
```

Hope you are understood this script...

Answer (score -3):

If you are using ajax code to populate that content, you can hide that div with a single line code.

Comment: I would suggest showing an example of this "single line code" to improve this answer